# EmberJS : Nested ArrayControllers sorting issue

Tags: sorting, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to sort the nested array. In order to sort an AFAIK we need to use ArrayController.

I have an arrays, like so :

```
[{
    id : 1,
    voucherno: 1,
    details : [{id : 3, srno : 3}, {id :2,srno : 2}, {id : 1, srno : 1}]
},
{
    id : 2,
    voucherno: 2,
    details : [{id : 6, srno : 3}, {id : 5, srno : 1}, {id: 4, srno : 2}]
}]
```

I want to  sort the data of details based on srno. After trying various different things this is what Ihave come up with. But it does not work.

My Model is :

```
App.Sale = DS.Model.extend({
  voucherno : DS.attr('number'),
  details : DS.hasMany('Detail',{ async: true })
});

App.Detail = DS.Model.extend({
  srno : DS.attr('number')
});
```

Route :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('sales', {
    path: '/'
}, function() {
    this.resource('sale', {
        path: "/:sale_id"
    }, function() {
        this.resource('details');
    });
});
});
```

Fiddle is here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11b78Lpz/1/)

Pl help, I saw all the answers around this, but none of them are working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected you jsfiddle. Rather outlet use `{{render}}` which also sets the specific controller. Its not sorting issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/11b78Lpz/3/

Basically replaced `{{outlet}}` which comes to following in sales template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sales">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div >Voucher No</div>
        <div class="row">
        {{#each model}}
            <div class="row col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 ">{{voucherno}}</div>
            {{render details details}}
        {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```